# Is there/ should there be an instruction / tutorial to use code to hide answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A great respect to puzzling SE that most users the command `>!` to hide their answer (and show up the answer only the visitor hover the mouse on screen), so that the visitors can apply their effort and doesn't get influenced.

Recently I've met [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18437/how-many-boxes-are-conductors); none of the answers used this technique; as a result they're hindering independence of thought.

So; could this feature be reminded with a *pop-up message* and the right-side yellow box (Only for this community (puzzling))?

[image: help box]

Though [the page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help) describing it, is linked to the yellow box; still the new users/ unexpert users may become less-prone to use this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what sort of puzzle it is.

More open ended ones don't really require spoilers, as its more a discussion, whereas puzzles with definite answers/steps should have spoilers. This is why some questions have answers with no spoilers, they don't spoil anything.

I don't think we really need that (furthermore, I don't know if we *can* change it) so it should be left as it is.